# Webpack failed to compile npm start

Tags: node.js, terminal, webpack, eslint

I got a project that I need to work on. I forked the project from gitlab, unzipped it into my workspace folder, ran terminal and the following commands

```
node --version
npm --version  
npm install  
npm init
npm start
```

This should have installed all devDependencies (I turned production to false) and the server should be up and running. However, I'm getting the following error

```
`ERROR in .//src/client/index.js
Module build failed: Error: No ESLint configuration found.
    at getLocalConfig ((dir)\node_modules\eslint\lib\config.js:162:35)
    at Config.getConfig ((dir)\node_modules\eslint\lib\config.js:259:26)
    at processText ((dir)\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:224:33)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText ((dir)\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:754:26)
    at lint ((dir)\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:44:31)
    at Object.module.exports ((dir)\node_modules\eslint-loader\index.js:181:3)
webpack: Failed to compile.`
```

I do have a eslintrc both on root dir and /src/client. What am I missing here ?